# Python infinite loop while determining the file size

Tags: python, filesize

I'm ending up with an infinite loop while trying to determine the size of the folders in the drive. Here is the code I'm using,

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
from sys import exit

filepath="P:\\GIS\\Data"

dirList=os.listdir(filepath)

for fname in dirList:   
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(filepath):

        print  root , sum([getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files]),
        print  "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"


print "All finished!"
```

I have tried saving the result in a variable but loop does not even reach to that step and starts looping infinitely Please could you advise me where it is going wrong?

Comment: What does it loop on? Like can you see when the files start repeating?

Comment: should the prints be parts of the second loop?

Comment: why you assume it is infinite loop instead of long computation operation? how many files do you have in this dirs?

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think you are infinitely looping.  I think you are repeating yourself.  I think you want `for root, dir, files in os.walk(fname)' though you might want that in a try except block to catch if it's a file

Comment: Any idea if there are symbolic links in any of your directories that point to a directory above it? That's the only way I can see you getting stuck in a loop, but I'm not sure `os.walk` even follows symlinks by default.

Comment: In that mentioned path there are around 70 folders and some of these folders contain subfolders and files. It is not even printing print "All finished!" line. All it is doing is repeating the loop so I have to interrupt the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
filepath="P:\\GIS\\Data"

dirList=os.listdir(filepath)

for fname in dirList:   
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(filepath):
```

You want to walk through every directory tree inside `"P:\\GIS\\Data"` and that's what you do in your second loop. However, you're doing this *for every directory inside this directory* because you iterate over `dirList` first, and you aren't even using `fname`.

Thus, for every directory in `dirList`, you do the same `print`s all over again, which gives you the wrong impression of an infinite loop.

Try removing `for fname in dirList:` and your script should reach its end.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to be an infinite loop or recursion because of [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) because

> By default, walk() will not walk down into symbolic links that resolve
>   to directories. Set followlinks to True to visit directories pointed
>   to by symlinks, on systems that support them.

But you do have a nested loop and this probably creates the impression that your code is infinite looping.

You could simplify this to avoid the nested loop

```
for root, dir, files in os.walk("P:\\GIS\\Data"):

    print  root , sum([getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files]),
    print  "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
```

this I believe will produce the desired result.

Comment: That's great, this worked, I just got rid of 'for name in dirlist:' line from my code.

Comment: You are most welcome. I am glad to have been of help. Since you are still new here, may i point out that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Comment: Yes will certainly, I will try again later as my current reputation doesn't allow me upvoting at the moment.